# Enabling network interface programmatically on Android

Tags: android, networking, interface, root

Starting from the issue:
Interface's state stays DOWN after connecting an OTG modem to my device.
A usb0 interface is created but doesn't change it's state to UP.

Solutions:
1. Manually do "su; ifconfig usb0 up" - Works, but manually  = bad.
2. Wrote a service that listens to "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED", then if it is the modem, a shell command would do the su + ifconfig.

The real question:
I would like to create the same service stated above, but without the need to be rooted (as changing the interface requires the use of "su").
If possible using standard Android permissions.
Any ideas?

Comment: you can do that with a jni function and a call to popen("ifconfig usb0 up", "r")

Comment: wouldn't the popen still require root permissions?